# How Do We Handle Runtime Errors From Room-Generated Paging Code?

Tags: android, android-room, android-paging

In [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/tree/v0.2/PagedFTS), I have [a DAO](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/blob/v0.2/PagedFTS/src/main/java/com/commonsware/room/fts/BookStore.kt) that is using Paging 2 on an FTS4 table to search it, using a user-supplied search expression:

```kotlin
  @Query("SELECT snippet(paragraphsFts) FROM paragraphs JOIN paragraphsFts "+
      "ON paragraphs.id == paragraphsFts.rowid WHERE paragraphsFts.prose "+
      "MATCH :search ORDER BY sequence")
  abstract fun filtered(search: String): DataSource.Factory<Int, String>
```

I have [a `BookRepository`](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/blob/v0.2/PagedFTS/src/main/java/com/commonsware/room/fts/BookRepository.kt) with a `filtered()` function that just passes through the call to the DAO, and I have [a `SearchViewModel`](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/blob/v0.2/PagedFTS/src/main/java/com/commonsware/room/fts/SearchViewModel.kt) that converts the `DataSource.Factory` to a `LiveData`:

```kotlin
class SearchViewModel(search: String, repo: BookRepository) : ViewModel() {
  val paragraphs = repo.filtered(search).toLiveData(pageSize = 15)
}
```

And I have [a fragment](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/blob/v0.2/PagedFTS/src/main/java/com/commonsware/room/fts/SearchFragment.kt) that observes the results:

```kotlin
    vm.paragraphs.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner) {
      adapter.submitList(it)
    }
```

This works fine, so long as the user does not enter a search expression with a syntax error. In that case, Room throws an exception, and I cannot see where I can catch it.

```
2020-08-30 08:50:50.923 13948-14019 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: arch_disk_io_3
    Process: com.commonsware.room.pagedfts, PID: 13948
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: malformed MATCH expression: [-9] (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:942)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:838)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:153)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:140)
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:232)
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:271)
        at androidx.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource.countItems(LimitOffsetDataSource.java:89)
        at androidx.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource.loadInitial(LimitOffsetDataSource.java:119)
        at androidx.paging.PositionalDataSource.dispatchLoadInitial(PositionalDataSource.java:286)
        at androidx.paging.TiledPagedList.<init>(TiledPagedList.java:107)
        at androidx.paging.PagedList.create(PagedList.java:229)
        at androidx.paging.PagedList$Builder.build(PagedList.java:388)
        at androidx.paging.LivePagedListBuilder$1.compute(LivePagedListBuilder.java:206)
        at androidx.paging.LivePagedListBuilder$1.compute(LivePagedListBuilder.java:171)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2.run(ComputableLiveData.java:101)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

The exception is occurring on a background thread used by the `LiveData` created by `toLiveData()`. So a `try`/`catch` in my `paragraphs` declaration will not work, as the exception is not thrown during creation of the `LiveData`. Wrapping my `observe()` call in a `try`/`catch` does not work, as the exception is not thrown on that thread.

If I were not using Paging, and instead had my DAO's `filtered()` function be a `suspend` function, I would get the exception directly and can catch and handle it in the viewmodel. Or, if `filtered()` were a blocking call, I would get the exception directly. Or, if `filtered()` returned an RxJava type, I would get the exception through normal RxJava exception handling approaches (e.g., `onError` lambdas). But I cannot quite figure out where I should be intercepting this exception when using Paging.

It's possible that Paging 3 has a solution for this, which would be great to know, though Paging 3 right now is still in alpha.

While I have not tried it, I suspect that if I supply my own `Executor` to `toLiveData()` that I could catch the exception there. Even if that is a possible workound, that seems like I am relying on a side effect (replacing how we schedule work on threads to be able to catch an exception).

Comment: Paging2 never really had the concept of errors built into it, and Paging3 tries to address this by adding an explicit error result type to PagingSource to signal to presentation layer that the error is recoverable. I'm on mobile so I haven't had a chance to try out your sample yet, but wanted to at least answer the latter question! My initial thought is to see if we can either wrap the DataSource generated by Room, or setup some specific error handling for a DAO.

Comment: Why do you not using `LIKE` instead of `MATCH` to prevent this error?

Comment: @aminography: Because I specifically want to use `MATCH` to enable full FTS syntax and to behave like a normal search engine. Suppose the user types in `foo`. `LIKE '%foo%'` matches `food`, which is not typical search engine behavior. SQLite's [documentation for FTS](https://sqlite.org/fts3.html) emphasizes the use of `MATCH`.